# Brillouin Zones in a nanowire

Tags: solid-state-physics

My professor told me something I didn't understand the other day: I was reading a paper on a crystalline nanowire (NW), and in the paper they look at how the band structure changes (from that of the unconfined bulk) as you make the diameter smaller (essentially, the confinement makes a valence and conduction band at a certain point of the Brillouin Zone (BZ) split apart).

Well, he essentially said that it's kind of useless to look at the bulk band structure when talking about a nanowire. I didn't really understand his reasoning for it, so that's what my question is about.

Now, here's what I thought (which must be incorrect in some part): I thought that the wave vector determines direction of travel of an electron and the Brillouin Zone gives all the directions you can travel in the crystal with respect to its crystal structure. And, the band structure diagram tells you the energy at and between the major points of the BZ, [like so.](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/_images/silicon_banddiagram.png) So, I thought, if you're confined to travel in one crystal direction like in the NW, if you want to find the dispersion relation $E(\vec k)$, you basically take a "slice" from the band structure diagram. For example, if the crystal orientation of your nanowire only let you travel along the $\Gamma -X$ direction in this BZ:

[image: BZ]

in the band structure diagram in the link above (assuming they went together, which they probably don't; I just took a couple random ones to illustrate my point), you'd only look at the region between $\Gamma$ ($\vec k = 0$) and $X$ ($\vec k = \vec b_1$). Essentially, that a NW is just a little piece of a bulk material, so it has the same band structure, but only part of it.

But apparently this isn't true, according to him (and I trust him, I just didn't understand him). Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks!